# change password at next logon...vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have the below code that "should" tick the box for change a local users password at next logon but I keep on getting errors.

The account is already created and on the server locally.

Any help please.

I have to do this in vbscript and not powershell due to older servers in our environment.

Code:

```
' get computer name
Set oWshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network" )
sComputerName = oWshNet.ComputerName

'Set Account Testuser Password Expired parameter
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT:// " & sComputerName & "/Testuser")
objUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
objUser.SetInfo
```

Error:

account.vbs(6, 1) (null): The network path was not found.

********EDIT**********************

Figured it out: (thanks google!)

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Const SUCCESS = 0

sUser = "TestUser"

' get the local computername with WScript.Network,
' or set sComputerName to a remote computer
Set oWshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
sComputerName = oWshNet.ComputerName

Set oUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & sComputerName & "/" & sUser)

oUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1
oUser.SetInfo

oShell.LogEvent SUCCESS, "Password Attribute Changed"
```

Comment: You should post your "Figured It Out" edit as an answer and accept that answer after two days.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

The answer to this was:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Const SUCCESS = 0 

sUser = "TestUser" 

' get the local computername with WScript.Network, 
' or set sComputerName to a remote computer 
Set oWshNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
sComputerName = oWshNet.ComputerName 

Set oUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & sComputerName & "/" & sUser) 

oUser.Put "PasswordExpired", 1 
oUser.SetInfo 

oShell.LogEvent SUCCESS, "Password Attribute Changed"
```